# close html form on javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I need close html form on javascript function.
This is my html:

```
<form id="f" method="post" name="form">
    <input type="button" value="okandclose" id="myButton" onclick='validateForm()' />
</form>
```

This is javascript.

```
 function validateForm() {
     var x = document.getElementById('sifOS').value;
     if (x == null || x == 0 || x == "0") {
         return false;
     } else {
         document.form.submit();

     }
 }
```

I need this on else.

Comment: After submit form what ????

Comment: Form must been post, then closed.

Comment: than you should submit with ajax otherwise your page will be reloaded

Comment: Form or the entire page?

Comment: Form. `window.close()` work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `window.close()` that will close the current browser window:

```
function validateForm() {
     var x = document.getElementById('sifOS').value;
     if (x == null || x == 0 || x == "0") {
         return false;
     }
     else {
         document.form.submit();
         window.close();

     }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. It is either going to submit the form or close the window. Not both.

Comment: What I tried for was, an html popup window, and none of the suggested solutions work for me. The work around I used was to reload the window .
window.location.reload().

Answer (score 0):

use ajax for this

after saving data in db you can hide the from , can display success message